# C++ Koenig(Argument-Dependent) Lookup: What if two namespaces functions in different namespaces have the same argument types?

Tags: c++, argument-dependent-lookup

What happens if there is a

`Foo::test(Foo::A &a, Bar::B &b, C &c);` and a

`Bar::test(Foo::A &a, Bar::B &b, C &c);`.

Are the namespaces of the arguments considered in-order by the compiler (the first argument taking precedence for the argument-dependent-lookup), or is this considered to be ambiguous?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It will be ambiguous. The overload set contains two equally valid overloads:

```
namespace Bar
{
    struct B;
}

namespace Foo
{
    struct A{};
    void test(A& , Bar::B&, int){}
}

namespace Bar
{
    struct B{};
    void test(Foo::A& , B&, int){}
}

int main() {
    Foo::A a; Bar::B b;
    test (a, b, 0);

    return 0;
}
```

results on gcc in:

> prog.cpp: In function 'int main()':
>   prog.cpp:21:15: error: call of overloaded 'test(Foo::A&, Bar::B&, int)' is ambiguous   test (a, b, 0);
>                  ^ prog.cpp:10:7: note: candidate: void Foo::test(Foo::A&, Bar::B&, int)   void test(A& , Bar::B&, int){}
>          ^ prog.cpp:16:7: note: candidate: void Bar::test(Foo::A&, Bar::B&, int)   void test(Foo::A& , B&, int){}

Answer (score 2):

According to the section 3.4.2 of the standard

> For each argument type T in the function call, there is a set of zero or more associated namespaces

So both namespaces `Foo` and `Bar` will be in the set of associated namespace. As function `test` is found in both, it will be ambiguous.